# Generate numbers from a set of digits

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to generate all possible combinations of three numbers derived from a set of numbers.
Let's say I have the digits 1 to 9 (once each) I would like to generate a triple of numbers like `14, 983, 7256` (but all possible combinations). So every digit can only be used once and all digits have to be used.

My first idea was to generate different sets of digits as a pool for each number  like so:

```
bin_arr = []
for i in range(1, 512):
    bin_arr.append([int(a) for a in ("{0:0b}".format(i))])

>>> bin_arr[257]
>>> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

and `compress` these with `'123456789'` but that doesnt seem to go anywhere.

Is there a way to do that in a clever way?

Comment: Does order matter? Is `[14, 983, 7256]` distinct from `[983, 14, 7256]`?

Comment: yes. in the end, the order does matter. but if I have all triples, I can do that afterwards. but if you are able to do it while generating the triples, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume one list like [14,983,2567] to be a number sequence 149832567,then we add two commas to it, one after 4 and the other after 3,so we generate a triple of numbers [14,983,2567].

So,how many number sequences can be generated?

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: a = range(1,10)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [4]: len(list(itertools.permutations(a,9)))
Out[4]: 362880
```

When we get a number sequence like  437865192, how many triple numbers can be generated?Combination

8*7/2 = 28(pick two gaps between the 9 numbers)

or use `itertools.combinations`

```
In [8]: len(list(itertools.combinations(list(range(8)),2)))
Out[8]: 28
```

given a sequence and we will get 28 combinations.

```
In [1]: a = ['2','3','6','4','9','1','7','8','5']

In [2]: import itertools

In [4]: for i in itertools.combinations(range(1,9),2):
...:     print [int(''.join(a[:i[0]])), int(''.join(a[i[0]:i[1]])), int(''.join(a[i[1]:]))]

[2, 3, 6491785]
[2, 36, 491785]
[2, 364, 91785]
[2, 3649, 1785]
[2, 36491, 785]
[2, 364917, 85]
[2, 3649178, 5]
[23, 6, 491785]
[23, 64, 91785]
[23, 649, 1785]
[23, 6491, 785]
[23, 64917, 85]
[23, 649178, 5]
[236, 4, 91785]
[236, 49, 1785]
[236, 491, 785]
[236, 4917, 85]
[236, 49178, 5]
[2364, 9, 1785]
[2364, 91, 785]
[2364, 917, 85]
[2364, 9178, 5]
[23649, 1, 785]
[23649, 17, 85]
[23649, 178, 5]
[236491, 7, 85]
[236491, 78, 5]
[2364917, 8, 5]
```

**so there are 10160640(362880*28) lists that will be generated.**

**THE FINAL CODE:**

```
In [15]: a=map(lambda x:str(x), range(1,10))

In [16]: a
Out[16]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

In [17]: result = []

In [18]: for seq in itertools.permutations(a,9):
    ...:     for i in itertools.combinations(range(1,9),2):
    ...:         result.append([int(''.join(seq[:i[0]])), int(''.join(seq[i[0]:i[1]])), int(''.join(seq[i[1]:]))])
    ...:

In [19]: len(result)
Out[19]: 10160640
```

Comment: but unfortunately it doesn't work. the lists in `result` are sorted. so it is always the original squence `a` with two separators in there. the permutation you do in step 1 somehow gets lost.

Comment: @sorry, the last append, i mistaken `seq` to the original a, so it is wrong.Now see my update.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, assuming order matters:

@ outcomes is a list of the desired options e.g. if you want a number with numerals 0-9, use output [0,1, . . ., 9].

@ length is the number of digits in each output number. You used up to 4 digits in your question, I assume there is some upper limit.

Use the function below to generate the permutations for each individual part of the triple and then feed that result back in to generate further permutations.

```
def gen_permutations(outcomes, length):
        ans = set([()])
        for dummy_idx in range(length):
            temp = set()
            for seq in ans: 
                for item in outcomes: #each possible outcome
                    new_seq = list(seq)
                    if len(outcomes) == 1 or item in new_seq:
                        continue
                    new_seq.append(item)
                    temp.add(tuple(new_seq))
            ans = temp

        return ans
```

Comment: There is no upper limit for each number. Just that there always have to be three and every digit can only get used once. So `(1, 2, 3456789)` is also a valid triple. Also, your function does not do what it should. It just gives me a list of permutations of the given length and provided digits.